# Accessing "name" of the subscribed variable in ko subscribe method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I know i can access the newValue of the subscribed variable but how can i access to the name of it:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < carSelects.length; i++) {
    var carId = $(carSelects[i]).attr('carId');
    self["cars_" + carId + "_selected"] = ko.observableArray();
    self["cars_" + carId + "_selected"].subscribe(function(newValue) {
       // here i want to access the name of the subsribed variable 
       // i.e. "cars_" + carId + "_selected"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < carSelects.length; i++) {
   var carId = $(carSelects[i]).attr('carId');
   (function(name){
       self[name] = ko.observableArray();
       self[name].subscribe(function(newValue) {
           alert(name);
       });
   })("cars_" + carId + "_selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As solution you can assign class with needed properties instead of ko.observableArray();

For example you have class

```
function CarClass(carId, changeCallback) {
   this.carId = carId;
   this.array = ko.observableArray();
   var self = this;

   self.array..subscribe(function(newValue) { 
      changeCallback(self.carId, newValue);
   });
}
```

And after that get car id within change function:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < carSelects.length; i++) {
    var carId = $(carSelects[i]).attr('carId');
    self["cars_" + carId + "_selected"] = new CarClass(carId, function(carId, newValue) {

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but you can obtain the name of the subscribed variable via the `event.srcElement` and get the value of the element's "data-bind" attribute, like below:

```
var id= $.trim(event.srcElement.attributes["data-bind"].value.split(':')[1])
```